# Unit test for parsing files, how to load the files from inside the application?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

i want to test a **service method** that **parses** an **excel file**
so i need help in the following:

1. i want to **create** a **test folder** for the excel files under **web-app**, how to do that ?
2. how to **load** the **file** in the unit test ?

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I typically put files into resources and load them as `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("my.xsl")`.

Please pay attention. If you put your file to the same package where your test is you just have to put the local name. Otherwise you should provide absolute path starting with `/`. If your application does not know to work with streams and requires files use `this.getClass().getResource("my.xsl").getFile()`.

Comment: where do you put the file, and how to load it ?

Comment: ok, here's what i tried: 1. first i didn't have a resources folder in test, so i created one as new source folder > and choose path src/test/resources. 2.added my file to the resources folder (i can see that resources folder exists now in test package and the file is in resources). 3. used the following code to load the file: `URL filePath = this.getClass().getResource("bulkDept.xlsx");
  File file = new File(filePath.toURI());` but i always get null pointer exception, please advise.

Comment: test package is as follows: **src>test>java,resources** and the **java folder** is > **Testing** (test package name) > **mytestclass**

Comment: Your test resouces should be under resources folder that is yet another source folder on the same level as `java`. If you are using maven you do not have other options: src/main/java, src/main/resources, src/test/java, src/test/resources

Comment: well, it worked fine as follows: `URL filePath = this.getClass().getResource("/bulkDept.xlsx");` i needed to add the slash before file name, and ideas why ?

Comment: can you please edit the answer to include the following way too: `URL filePath = this.getClass().getResource("/bulkDept.xlsx"); File file = new File(filePath.toURI());`